# Finding word in NSString and checking before and after character this word?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring

How to find word in `NSString` and check characters before and after this word?

`"This pattern has two parts separated by the"`

How to find `tern` and how to check the character before and after

Before word character:`"t"`
After word character:`" "`

Comment: This question is very unclear. Please clarify what you are trying to do.

Comment: How to get character using 
NSUInteger indexOfChar1 = scanner.scanLocation - 1;
NSUInteger indexOfChar2 = scanner.scanLocation + string.length;

Comment: searching word in string after if searching word found in string then check searching word before  and after what character ? and how to get this character ?
example :" This pattern has two parts separated by the " that string find word "tern"  tern before and after charcter how to get 
eg . parttern  -- and find word tern and tern before character is "t" and after character is space or " "

Comment: @UmerAfzal I updated my answer with getting the characters out of indexes.

Comment: @UmerAfzal, update the question instead of answering through comments. It will help get better answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an implementation using Regular Expressions

```
NSString *testString= @"This pattern has two parts separated by the";
NSString *regexString = @"(.)(tern)(.)";

NSRegularExpression* exp = [NSRegularExpression 
  regularExpressionWithPattern:regexString 
  options:NSRegularExpressionSearch error:&error];

if (error) {
    NSLog(@"%@", error);
} else {
    NSTextCheckingResult* result = [exp firstMatchInString:testString options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [testString length] ) ];

if (result) {

NSRange groupOne = [result rangeAtIndex:1]; // 0 is the WHOLE string.
NSRange groupTwo = [result rangeAtIndex:2];
NSRange groupThree = [result rangeAtIndex:3];

NSLog(@"[%@][%@][%@]", 
     [testString substringWithRange:groupOne],
     [testString substringWithRange:groupTwo],
     [testString substringWithRange:groupThree] );
  }
}
```

Results:

```
[t][tern][ ]
```

Comment: If the regex was modified to (.?)(tern)(.?) this would allow for the matching of "edge" case:  term occurring at front or end of string

Comment: It should be noted that his prof will never believe he figured out how to use REs and hence will know that he copied the answer off he web.

Answer (score 3):

You can use **`NSScanner`** to get indexes of these two characters.

Example:

```
NSString *string = @"tern";
NSScanner *scanner = [[NSScanner alloc] initWithString:@"This pattern has two parts separated by the"];

[scanner scanUpToString:string intoString:nil];

NSUInteger indexOfChar1 = scanner.scanLocation - 1;
NSUInteger indexOfChar2 = scanner.scanLocation + string.length;
```

You can also use a **`rangeOfString`** method:

Example:

```
NSRange range = [sourceString rangeOfString:stringToLookFor];
NSUInteger indexOfChar1 = range.location - 1;
NSUInteger indexOfChar2 = range.location +range.length + 1;
```

Then, when you have indexes, getting the characters is **easy**:

```
NSString *firstCharacter = [sourceString substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(indexOfChar1, 1)];
NSString *secondCharacter = [sourceString substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(indexOfChar2, 1)];
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Its better to get pre and post character in NSString to avoid handling of unicode characters.

```
NSString * testString = @"This pattern has two parts separated by the";
NSString * preString;
NSString * postString;
NSUInteger maxRange;

NSRange range = [testString rangeOfString:@"tern"];


if(range.location == NSNotFound){
    NSLog(@"Not found");
    return;
}

if (range.location==0) {
    preString=nil;
}
else{
    preString = [testString substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(range.location-1,1)];
}

maxRange = NSMaxRange(range);

if ( maxRange >=testString.length ) {
    postString = nil;
}
else{
    postString = [testString substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(range.location+range.length, 1)];
}
```